Julian date databricks SQL
We have requirement to construct Delta lake table which has Calendar dates and  its corresponding Julian dates for next 5 years . Is there any function present with data bricks sql which help me generate such table.
We are looking for below table

EndOfMonth and EndofYear nothing but it indicates given date is endofmonth or EndOfyear
for 31-Aug-2024  EndofMonth Should be 1
for 31-Dec-2024 EndofYear should have value 1

As Wikipedia tells us:

For any given event during the years from 1901 through 2099, its date according to the Julian calendar is 13 days behind its corresponding Gregorian date (for instance Julian 1 January falls on Gregorian 14 January).

Therefore, assuming you'll only nagivate within that range, it's quite straightforward:
SELECT d as calendar_date,
       d - interval '13' days as julian_date,
       last_day(d) = d as end_of_month,
       end_of_month and month(d) = 12 as end_of_year
  FROM (SELECT explode(sequence(current_date(), current_date() + interval '5' year)) as d);
+-------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
|calendar_date|julian_date|end_of_month|end_of_year|
+-------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
|2024-08-22   |2024-08-09 |false       |false      |
|2024-08-23   |2024-08-10 |false       |false      |
|2024-08-24   |2024-08-11 |false       |false      |
|2024-08-25   |2024-08-12 |false       |false      |
|2024-08-26   |2024-08-13 |false       |false      |
|2024-08-27   |2024-08-14 |false       |false      |
|2024-08-28   |2024-08-15 |false       |false      |
|2024-08-29   |2024-08-16 |false       |false      |
|2024-08-30   |2024-08-17 |false       |false      |
|2024-08-31   |2024-08-18 |true        |false      |
|2024-09-01   |2024-08-19 |false       |false      |
+-------------+-----------+------------+-----------+


Thank for the update , But Looking for Julian date in format(YYddd) YY - Year and dd- Calendar day.
Date: 23-Aug-2024
Julian Date: 24236
Reference- https://www.longpelaexpertise.com.au/toolsJulian.php

Use date_format function to display it in whatever format is needed (here you probably want: date_format(d, 'yyyyDDD'))
